# HTML multiple selection listbox spread across multiple columns

Tags: html, html-select

I would like to make a multiple selection listbox in HTML that can have it's values spread across multiple columns.

I do NOT want multiple columns for each option, I would like all the options to spread across the combo box, so it looks something like a grid of options, perhaps 4 high by 5 wide.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: I've tried using the size attribute, but that only restricts the height, and doesn't widen the box. I have tried using the width attribute in case forcing the width to be larger would generate new columns but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: @Šime Really? That sucks. I've seen it done in heaps of other programming languages, so I assumed you could do it in HTML too. Oh well.

Comment: You could use JavaScript to generate a "fake" multi-column select box...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using a listbox control.

For this kind of thing I would use individual checkboxes instead. Use the <label for> tag to attach the checkbox to a label. You can arrange the items any way you like.

If you want to get fancy, you can use the [JQueryUI Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid) control.

Comment: Yea, I might end up doing that, but having a large amount of checkboxes looks quite messy.